# Cannot install Nodejs 14 on Ubuntu 18

Tags: node.js

I want to install node 14 on Ubuntu 18 but It only install version 8

```
 sudo apt -y install curl dirmngr apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates

 curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
```

console output

```
+ apt-get update
Obter:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease [6.263 B]
Atingido:2 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                           
Atingido:3 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                              
Atingido:4 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                   
Atingido:5 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                 
Err:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                           
  As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Obter:6 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease [5.588 B]                                                    
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mapopa/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                         
Atingido:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                    
Atingido:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease                                  
Err:6 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease                                                                
  As seguintes assinaturas eram inválidas: EXPKEYSIG 18DF3741CDFFDE29 philandro Software GmbH <info@philandro.com>
Atingido:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease                             
Atingido:11 https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/bionic pgadmin4 InRelease                 
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mapopa/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release                                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto                    
W: Erro GPG: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease: As assinaturas a seguir não puderam ser verificadas devido à chave pública não estar disponível: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease: As seguintes assinaturas eram inválidas: EXPKEYSIG 18DF3741CDFFDE29 philandro Software GmbH <info@philandro.com>
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mapopa/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Has nothing to do with node. Try just `sudo apt-update` and i bet you get the same error messages.